# Devise failing to generate views with error "'require': cannot load such file -- devise/orm/false"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to generate views with devise upon adding Devise to an existing app.  The `rails g devise:install` step completes successfully, but when I try to `rails g devise:views`, I get an error saying `'require': cannot load such file -- devise/orm/false`

Answer (score 0):

After I did a lot of digging, I realized that my problem was that the first step appeared to be completing successfully, but in reality, I had an atypical Rails `config/application.rb` where I wasn't `require 'rails/all'` but instead just requiring the modules I needed (which didn't include active_record at the time).  I ended up fixing that along the way, but because that wasn't included in the `application.rb` when I ran `rails g devise:install`, the line `require 'devise/orm/false'` persisted in the auto-generated `config/initializers/devise.rb`, and thus would fail anytime trying to load.  I'm sure the simple solution is just to replace the word "false" there with "active_record", but I went ahead and just deleted the whole file and reran the `rails g devise:install` command in case there was something else in there that was messed up.

tl;dr make sure you are including rails/active_record before you run `rails g devise:install`, and if you didn't, recreate the file once you've included it in your `config/application.rb`